# Error while building Linphone for windows

Tags: mingw, msys, sip-server, linphone

I am trying to build linphone for windows by following the instructions in `Readme.mingw` using MinGw/Msys. There is no issues till the download of belle-sip package.

When I run `./autogen.sh` I am getting the below error.

```
Generating buildipts in belle-sip...
+ libtoolize --copy --force
libtoolize: $pkgltdldir is not a directory: `/mingw/share/libtool'
+ aclocal -I /share/aclocal
Can't locate Automake/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/share/automake-1.
11 /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/msys
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_
perl/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) a
t /c/MinGW/bin/aclocal-1.11 line 37.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/MinGW/bin/aclocal-1.11 line 37.
+ autoheader
Can't locate Autom4te/ChannelDefs.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/share/autoco
nf /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/msys
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_
perl/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) a
t /c/MinGW/bin/autoheader-2.68 line 42.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/MinGW/bin/autoheader-2.68 line 42.
+ automake --force-missing --add-missing --copy
Can't locate Automake/Struct.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/share/automake-1.
11 /usr/lib/perl5/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8/msys
/usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_
perl/5.8/msys /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl/5.8 .) a
t /c/MinGW/bin/automake-1.11 line 47.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at /c/MinGW/bin/automake-1.11 line 47.
+ autoconf
/c/MinGW/bin/autoconf-2.68: line 501: /mingw/bin/autom4te-2.68: No such file or
directory
/c/MinGW/bin/autoconf-2.68: line 501: exec: /mingw/bin/autom4te-2.68: cannot exe
cute: No such file or directory
```

Can anyone point out where I went wrong and give the steps for successful build?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

Given this specific part of the error output:

> Can't locate Automake/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
>   /mingw/share/automake-1. 11
>   ....

It looks that the `/mingw` path does not exist, which means it should be added as an alias to `c:\mingw` in the `fstab` file.

See the [MinGW Installation Notes](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/Getting_Started#toc2) for a step-by-step howto.

Comment: Just renaming `c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab.sample` to `c:\MinGW\msys\1.0\etc\fstab` did the trick for me. That file already had a line `c:/mingw  /mingw`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create shortcut of AllPrograms->Start menu->minGW->msys.bat 
if this opens correctly that means msys is configured correctly with minGW.

For automake errors.
1. Open MinGW installation manager. 
MinGW Installation Manager[C:/MinGW/bin      mingw-get.exe]

//All automake, libtool, autoconf, aclocal, autoheader dependencies must be installed.
I hope this should resolve your issue.

Keep me posting if it still does'nt work.

Amit