# aclocal not found for mingw sh autogen.sh execution

Tags: windows, mingw

i'm trying to execute

```
./autogen.sh
```

script in cppunit folder from

http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/cppunit

but in a mingw shell(sh) i get next error:

```
error: aclocal not found
```

aclocal m4 scripts are in

```
c:\MinGW\share\
```

directory.

How to fix that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've tried to directly run aclocal from shell sh.

And it printed another error message:

```
Can't locate Automake/Config.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /mingw/...
```

As in question: [Error while building Linphone for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21162622/error-while-building-linphone-for-windows)

So i mounter /mingw by command:

```
mount c:/mingw /mingw
```

and script works now.

Answer (score 15):

Had a similar problem when compiling a libmodbus library (it uses the same build principle). I have entered the following commands in MSYS shell:

```
pacman -S msys/libtool

pacman -S msys/autoconf

pacman -S msys/automake-wrapper
```

After that I was able to execute autogen.sh

Answer (score 10):

it happens on ubuntu as well to overcome to this in ubuntu install automake libtool

```
apt-get install automake libtool
```

Answer (score 1):

This did for me:

```
pacman -S --needed --noconfirm autoconf automake libtool make
```

Answer (score 0):

`Aclocal` is part of `automake` tools, not a standalone package. 
Install from source to get latest version or use apt

> sudo apt-get install automake

OR

```
VERSION=1.15
    wget ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz &> /dev/null
    if [ -f "automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz" ]; then
            tar -xzf automake-${VERSION}.tar.gz
            cd automake-${VERSION}/
            ./configure
            make && make install
            echo -e "\e[1;39m[   \e[1;32mOK\e[39m   ] automake-${VERSION} installed\e[0;39m"

        else
            echo -e "\e[1;39m[   \e[31mError\e[39m   ] cannot fetch file from ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/automake/ \e[0;39m"
            exit 1
fi
```

to install from source

Comment: Don't get the downvotes. This works fine for me on Linux

Comment: This question isn't about Linux, it's about MinGW.